wrong finder address of brand new laptop which, won't recognize any devices
I brought my new laptop home and found that it won't connect with devices, even when they are plugged in to the laptop. It doesn't recognize them. When I checked the finder locations I found that the laptop thinks it resides at an address a block away. The devices have the correct address. Any ideas?

What do you mean by "at an address a block away"? Is that in terms of network addresses or in terms of street addresses?
